# Setting matrixWorld property of a three.js object

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, three.js, transform

I have an array containing a 4x4 transformation matrix encoding rotation and position data (I've already confirmed that this matrix represents a valid transformation in Octave). I'd like to set the matrixWorld property of a three.js object (an [Object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Object3D)) using the contents of this array, i.e., set the position and rotation of the object based on the transformation matrix.

According to [this page](http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Matrix_transformations) from the three.js documentation and various questions asked here (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320817/using-matrices-to-transform-the-three-js-scene-graph) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470156/setting-the-camera-matrix-manually-in-threejs)), it seems the key is to set `nameOfObject.matrixAutoUpdate` to false. However, with this accounted for, I've tried a variety of approaches to set `nameOfObject.matrixWorld` and none of them change the location where the object is rendered: it remains at the origin with no rotation, as is the case when `matrixWorld` is the 4x4 identity matrix.

Here's what I've tried (this code is inside an update method before `render()` is called):

```
// Setting up a three.js matrix
var tempMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
tempMatrix.fromArray(arrayContainingTransformationMatrix);

// Values are set as expected
console.log(tempMatrix.elements);

// Note that the approaches below were tried one at a time

// First approach (doesn't work)
nameOfObject.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
nameOfObject.matrixWorld.copy(tempMatrix);

// Second approach (also doesn't work)
// Based on the second SO question linked above
nameOfObject.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
nameOfObject.matrix.copy(tempMatrix);
nameOfObject.updateMatrixWorld(true);

// Third approach (this doesn't work either, unfortunately)
nameOfObject.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
nameOfObject.matrixWorld.fromArray(arrayContainingTransformationMatrix);

// Appears to be set correctly regardless of which approach is used
console.log(sphere1.matrixWorld.elements);
```

A few notes:

- I'd expect that it's not actually necessary to set `matrixAutoUpdate` to false inside every iteration, but for now I've done so just to play it safe.
- If `nameOfObject.position` is modified based on the values in the fourth column of the transformation matrix instead of changing `matrixWorld`, the object's position changes as expected, so this doesn't appear to be a rendering issue.
- I've read in multiple locations that `updateMatrix()` shouldn't be called when manually setting the matrix as it overwrites it based on the `position` and `rotation` properties. I'd assume `updateMatrixWorld()` is subject to similar considerations, but I haven't found as much discussion of what it does.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Worst case I'll look through the source, but three.js has been quite easy to use thus far and I suspect I'm simply missing something.

Comment: You can only set the object's matrix. You can't set the object's world matrix. Is this your question? "How can I set `object.matrix` so that it results in a particular `object.matrixWorld` -- taking into account the transforms of the object's parents?"

Comment: If the object's world matrix is read-only, that answers my question. I assumed it could be set because the `matrixWorld` property isn't labelled "readonly" in the [Object3D docs](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Object3D) (the descriptions for other read-only properties, e.g., `id`, start with "readonly").

Comment: It is not read-only. The renderer is resetting it.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the renderer from doing so? (I realize this isn't essential given the `attach` and `detach` methods in `SceneUtils`.) The description of `matrixAutoUpdate` seems to imply that setting it to false should prevent both `matrix` and `matrixWorld` from updating, but this appears to only prevent `matrix` from being updated.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying to achieve. If you answer the question in my first comment, that would be helpful.

Comment: My question is not "How can I set `object.matrix` so that it results in a particular `object.matrixWorld` -- taking into account the transforms of the object's parents?". It's essentially "Can `matrixWorld` be set directly?" It seems that the answer is, "yes, but the renderer will reset it based on `matrix` and the location of the object's parent, thus setting `matrixWorld` directly has no effect".

Comment: You have it right. And FWIW, what I was guessing was your question is doable by setting `object.matrix` to be the product of (1) the inverse of `parent.matrixWorld` and (2) your desired matrix.

Answer (score 2):

For now, I was able to achieve the desired result by setting the object's `matrix` property (the local transform relative to the object's parent). Since the object's parent is `scene`, code like this works:

```
scene.add(nameOfObject);

// Using this transformation matrix (translation of two units along the x axis):
// 1 0 0 2
// 0 1 0 0
// 0 0 1 0
// 0 0 0 1

// Column-major version of the transformation
var tempArrayCM = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1];
// Per the docs, Matrix4.fromArray() uses column-major format

// Row-major version of the transformation
var matrixT = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrixT.set(1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
// Per the docs, Matrix4.set() uses row-major format

nameOfObject.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

nameOfObject.matrix.fromArray(tempArrayCM); // This works

//nameOfObject.matrix.copy(matrixT); // This also works

//nameOfObject.matrixWorld.fromArray(tempArrayCM); // No effect

//nameOfObject.matrixWorld.copy(matrixT); // No effect
```

It seems setting `matrixWorld` just doesn't work. I suppose this is fine when the object in question is a child of `scene`, but I can imagine this causing problems if the object is a child of a child of `scene` and it's necessary to set its world position independent of its parent (**edit:** it appears that the `attach` and `detach` methods of [SceneUtils](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras/SceneUtils) would permit this, albeit indirectly).

I won't be marking this as the answer since it's really just a workaround that applies only when the object's parent is `scene`.

An aside: I find it a little odd that `Matrix4.set()` uses row-major order but `Matrix4.fromArray()` and `Matrix4.elements` use column-major order.

Comment: You have to have .updateMatrix() in your loop, right?

Comment: No, but its omission is consistent with [what I've read about](http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Matrix_transformations) `updateMatrix()` (namely that it shouldn't be called when setting `matrix` manually as it will overwrite the transform with one calculated using the `position` and `rotation` properties).

Comment: `Matrix4.set()` uses row-major order so the code is human-readable when printed as a block in 4 lines. `Matrix4.elements` uses column-major order to be webGL-compatible. `Matrix4.fromArray()` uses column-major order to be compatible with `Matrix4.elements`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to directly set matrixWorld because Scene extends Object3D, i.e. Scene has it's own matrix and all objects in Scene are also children of Object3D, and an Object3D's transform should affect its children.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source.

```
updateMatrix: function () {
        this.matrix.compose( this.position, this.quaternion, this.scale );
        this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
    },
```

We see that an Object3D's matrix is built from it position, quaternion and scale parameters.

So rather than setting the matrix its might be easier to set the individual parts making up the matrix.

For example this code translates the scene so its centered on the middle of the range and scales it to fit.

```
    let xrange = xmax-xmin, yrange = ymax-ymin, zrange = zmax-zmin;
    let range = (xrange+yrange+zrange)/3;
    scene.scale.set(2/range,2/range,2/range);
    scene.position.set( -(xmax+xmin)/2, -(ymax+ymin)/2, -(zmax+zmin)/2); 
    seene.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, "I [had] an array containing a 4x4 transformation matrix encoding rotation and position data", not separate representations of the position and orientation. (The source of the transforms was an old NDI NIR optical tracker that could only produce transformation matrices.) It's possible to decompose a transformation matrix, but doing so would have added unnecessary computational load since threejs would have had to generate the transformation matrix itself anyway; accordingly, giving it the transformation matrix that was already available was more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, we will use the following methods to update matrixWorld of an object.

```
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh();
    const matrixWorld = new THREE.Matrix4();
    // this will update mesh position, quaternion and scale with new matrix.
    matrixWorld.decompose(mesh.position, mesh.quaternion, mesh.scale);
```

This is official recommendations in three doc.

https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Matrix-transformations